# Render partial view as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I know this looks like a duplicate question, but please read the whole question before marking it as duplicate.

First of all, I'm [simulating the windows service in my ASP web application](http://beckelman.net/2008/09/20/simulate-a-windows-service-using-aspnet-to-run-scheduled-jobs/) to send weekly emails, so in `Global.asax` I'm running my function that will send the emails.

Now the emails content is in HTML and I want to render the views to get the content. The problem is that in my function, I don't have any of the following :

- `Controller`
- `ControllerContext`
- `HttpContext`
- `RoutData`
- ... & much more. Which makes sense, because the function was invoked as a callback not as a HTTP request action.

I tried to use the `RazorEngine` to use the partial as a template by reading the file then using `Razor.Parse()` method. But I faced a lot of problems from this approach, because nothing is included in the template. What I mean is: it keeps telling me that *The name "Html" does not exist in the current context*  OR `'CompiledRazorTemplates.Dynamic.becdccabecff' does not contain a definition for 'Html'` even if I include the `System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

how can I solve this issue?.

Comment: Razor engine requires httpcontext, viewcontext to parse the view files. You could rather use html email templates with tokens in a separate file and use that in the scheduled tasks to prepare the final emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is assuming you developed a real NT service and use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) to send a http request to your partial view and receive the response as string and use it to make up your email. However, you can have `HttpContext` in `RunScheduledTasks` method by making some changes in `Scheduler` class.

```
 public delegate void Callback();
```

to

```
 public delegate void Callback(HttpContext httpContext);
```

add `cache.Current_HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;` to the Run method

```
    public static void Run(string name, int minutes, Callback callbackMethod)
    {
        _numberOfMinutes = minutes;

        CacheItem cache = new CacheItem();
        cache.Name = name;
        cache.Callback = callbackMethod;
        cache.Cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
        cache.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
        cache.Current_HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        AddCacheObject(cache);
    }
```

change `CacheCallback` to

```
    private static void CacheCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
        CacheItem obj_cache = (CacheItem)value;
        if (obj_cache.LastRun < DateTime.Now)
        {
            if (obj_cache.Callback != null)
            {
                obj_cache.Callback.Invoke(obj_cache.Current_HttpContext);
            }
            obj_cache.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
        }
        AddCacheObject(obj_cache);
    }
```

**Edited:**
How to use `HttpClient`

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/controller/action/");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Sir, I dont think that the `HttpContext is not null` in the Global.asax Application start... right?

Comment: Yes, you are right it is not null, but in your callback method it is null, because the callback method invoked from the System.Web.Caching.Cache thread

Comment: In the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax` HttpContext is not null. But in your callback method it is null because the callback method invoked from the System.Web.Caching.Cache thread.

Comment: You are right sir, i just have one question, can we pull ControllerContext from HttpContext

Comment: No, we cannot get `ControllerContext`. As I mentioned in the answer best way to do this is, getting your partial view by `HttpClient` `GetAsync` as you must do in NT Service or Console Application.

Comment: with some tuning it worked, thanks alot for all you help sir,

Answer (score 0):

Without using 3rd party library, one can use this method to generate string of view in Global.asax.cs file

```
public class EmptyController : Controller { }

public string GetView(string viewName)
   {
   //Create an instance of empty controller
   Controller controller = new EmptyController();

   //Create an instance of Controller Context
   var ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, controller);

   //Create a string writer
   using (var sw = new StringWriter())
   {
      //get the master layout
      var master = Request.IsAuthenticated ? "_InternalLayout" : "_ExternalLayout";

      //Get the view result using context controller, partial view and the master layout
      var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, master);

      //Crete the view context using the controller context, viewResult's view, string writer and ViewData and TempData
      var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);

      //Render the view in the string writer
      viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

      //release the view
      viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

      //return the view stored in string writer as string
      return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
   }
}
```